# Proof that every modally closed sentence expresses a non contingent proposition

Tags: logic

In Paul Herricks' "Introduction to Logic" there stands: "...it can be rigorously proven that every modally closed sentence of ML expresses a noncontingent proposition, assuming semantics for S5."
But he does not provide a proof and furthermore, I dont find a proof online. Can someone please explain to me why that is true or show me a proof?

Comment: What do "modally closed" and "noncontingent" mean?

Comment: A formula P is "modally closed" just in case every sentence letter appears within the scope of a modal operator.
For example: something like this: □(P ⇒ Q) but not something like this: □P&Q.
Noncontingent means necessarily true or necessarily false.